# Programaticly moving partitions on windows c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-xp

I am trying to create an application that will *programatically* move a windows partition on the hard drive, from Sector X to Sector Y.

**What i have tried so far:**

- copy the effective data from starting sector X to sector Y (read/write)
- update the partition table on the MBR so the specific partition is at offset Y
  Doing the second step I am using IOCTL_DISK_SET_DRIVE_LAYOUT control code of the DeviceIoControl function, but I always end up in ***blue screen*** ( *kernel_stack_inpage_error* )

What else am I missing?

My solution is using c++/winapi and i have tried it only on windows XP .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to move a partition Windows is currently accessing (or even the partition Windows is currently installed on)?

This would be a very bad idea because the caching algorithms would no longer work correctly in this case so the blue screen is not very surprising.

Comment: Yes I am trying to move the windows partition